# Compiling program with cryptopp

Tags: c++, hash, compiler-errors

inside generate.cpp

```
...
if (!hash_enabled.empty()) {
            Hash hash;
            std::string hashed_combination = hash.get_hash(combination, hash_enabled);
            hashed_combination = ":" + hashed_combination;
            combination += hashed_combination;
}
...
```

inside hash.cpp

```
#include <cryptopp/md2.h>
#include <cryptopp/md4.h>
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha3.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
...

std::string get_hash(const std::string& data, const std::string& hash_function) {

    if (hash_function == "md2") {
        Hash::MD MD;
        return MD.MD2(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "md4") {
        Hash::MD MD;
        return MD.MD4(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "md5") {
        Hash::MD MD;
        return MD.MD5(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha1-160") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA1 SHA1;
        return SHA1.SHA1_160(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha2-224") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA2 SHA2;
        return SHA2.SHA2_224(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha2-256") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA2 SHA2;
        return SHA2.SHA2_256(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha2-384") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA2 SHA2;
        return SHA2.SHA2_384(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha2-512") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA2 SHA2;
        return SHA2.SHA2_512(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha3-224") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA3 SHA3;
        return SHA3.SHA3_224(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha3-256") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA3 SHA3;
        return SHA3.SHA3_256(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha3-384") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA3 SHA3;
        return SHA3.SHA3_384(data);
    } else if (hash_function == "sha3-512") {
        Hash::SHA::SHA3 SHA3;
        return SHA3.SHA3_512(data);
    }

    return "";
}

std::string MD2(const std::string& data) {
    CryptoPP::Weak1::MD2 hash;
    std::string digest;

    CryptoPP::StringSource(data, true,
        new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash,
            new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest)
            )
        )
    );

    return digest;
}

...
```

Still getting this error:

```
g++ -I"C:\Users\Khakis\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion Nova\bin\mingw\include" -I"C:\msys64\ucrt64\include" .\kplg.cpp .\help.cpp .\get_info.cpp .\generate.cpp .\hash.cpp -o .\khakis.exe -LC:\msys64\ucrt64\include\cryptopp -lcryptopp
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcryptopp: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I missing something? Some libraries or something?
As you can see the command for compiling looks like:
`g++ ./kplg.cpp ./help.cpp ./get_info.cpp ./generate.cpp ./hash.cpp -o ./khakis.exe`
I have no idea

Importing so many things fixing typo in not including the hash.cpp in the g++ command. Searching on the internet and so much more

Comment: `-L` option should point to place where `libcryptocpp.a` file is located, not to include directories.

Comment: I see no libcryptocpp.a, only libcrypto.a. Is the compilation command correct, then?

Comment: Then you need `-lcrypto` not `-lcryptopp`

Comment: `(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `Hash::MD::MD2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'` and same for MD4,5, SHA, etc. by using:
`g++ .\kplg.cpp .\help.cpp .\get_info.cpp .\generate.cpp .\hash.cpp -o .\khakis.exe -lcrypto`

Comment: libcrypto.a is one of OpenSSL libraries and is irrelevant to crypto++.

Answer (score 0):

`-L` must point to the library `libcryptopp.a` base directory, perhaps:

```
-LC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib -lcryptopp
```

`pkg-config libcrypto++ --libs` can be used for getting the linker flags.

Answer (score -2):

The -L option must be pointing to the library folder (where the file libcryptopp.so or .a is located)

If you want to includes the headers (the include folder with all the .h files) you must use the -I option so you need to have something like:

```
-LC:\msys64\ucrt64\{lib64?}\cryptopp -IC:\msys64\ucrt64\include\cryptopp -lcryptopp
```

You can also compile the libraries yourself, check the INSTALL file provided with cryptopp releases